# How to find which superclass contains a name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, method-resolution-order

I'm working with some code that I didn't write (so don't blame me for the crazyness).  This is Python 3.9.  I've got:

```
    try:
        del self.userinfo  # force reload
        if self.userinfo['name'] == self.user():
            self._loginstatus = login.LoginStatus.AS_USER
            return
```

My first thought was WTF?  It deletes self.userinfo and then immediately references it?  How can be?  Then I realized what must be going on is that self.userinfo is also defined in some superclass, of which there are a bunch:

```
class APISite(
    BaseSite,
    EchoMixin,
    FlowMixin,
    GeneratorsMixin,
    GeoDataMixin,
    GlobalUsageMixin,
    LinterMixin,
    PageImagesMixin,
    ProofreadPageMixin,
    TextExtractsMixin,
    ThanksFlowMixin,
    ThanksMixin,
    UrlShortenerMixin,
    WikibaseClientMixin,
):
```

Is there some way to get Python to tell me in which of those superclasses it's finding self.userinfo?

Comment: To your main question I don't know how to check the superclass. But the code reminds me some code I was reading some time ago. They use a "LazyDict" that use a loader that load the dict entries the first time is accessed for that reason `del` clear the dict and when is accessed again repopulate the dict. Maybe is the same kind of logic behind.

Answer (score 0):

Ugh.  Nevermind.  There's:

```
@property
def userinfo(self) -> Dict[str, Any]:
```

and

```
@userinfo.deleter
def userinfo(self) -> None:
    """Delete cached userinfo.

    .. versionadded:: 5.5
    """
    if hasattr(self, '_userinfo'):
        del self._userinfo
```

somebody was trying to be clever and fancy.

Comment: This isn’t really an answer to your question, even though it solves the problem that your question was trying to solve, so it’s unlikely to be helpful to anyone else with that same question (unless they happen to be working in your specific codebase, which I agree kinda reeks of someone trying to be “clever”…)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code that iterates over all of `MyClass`'s super classes and uses the built-in `vars()` function to check if the contain the variable name contained in `var`:

```
class SuperClass1:
    user_info = 1

class SuperClass2:
    other_var = 2

class MyClass(SuperClass1, SuperClass2):
    @staticmethod
    def find_var(var):
        for superclass in MyClass.__bases__:
            if var in vars(superclass):
                return superclass

test = MyClass()
print(test.find_var("user_info")) # Output: <class '__main__.SuperClass1'>
```

`vars()`:  https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars

`class.__bases__`:  https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?#class.%5F%5Fbases%5F%5F